# Need help to parse and print only 'category' values either using jq or jsawk or shell script

Tags: json, jq, jsawk

Need help to parse and print only `category` values either using jq or jsawk or shell script.

```
{
  "fine_grained": {
    "dog": [
      {
        "category": "cocker spaniel",
        "mark": 0.9958831668
      }
    ]
  },
  "coarse": [
    {
      "category": "dog",
      "mark": 0.948208034
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Parse and print 'category' values from *what*?

Comment: Sorry, but we have no idea what you're asking for. Please provide a sample input, its expected output and your best attempt at solving the problem so far.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all `category` values are simple strings and you want all category values, regardless of where it is in the JSON, you could use this filter using jq:

```
.. | objects.category // empty
```

This returns the following strings:

```
"cocker spaniel"
"dog"
```

Comment: '.. | objects.category ' did not work. it says objects.category command not found

Comment: You're using `jq` right? That's not a command, it's a filter you pass in to `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **leaf_paths** and **select** to find all the paths with a leaf "category" member and then extract the corresponding values with **foreach**

```
foreach (leaf_paths | select(.[-1] == "category")) as $p (
    .
  ; .
  ; getpath($p)
)
```

If your input is in a file called `input.json` and the above filter is in a file called `filter.jq` then the shell command

```
jq -f filter.jq input.json
```

should produce

```
"cocker spaniel"
"dog"
```

You can use the `-r` flag if you don't want the quotes in the output.

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
  (leaf_paths | select(.[-1] == "category")) as $p
| getpath($p)
```